# Template, branching on length for array from compile-time initializer list

Tags: c++, templates

Basically what I tried to do is

```
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

template <class... Fs>
auto F(const std::initializer_list<double>& vars, const Fs&... exprs) {
    return std::array<double, vars.size()>{};
}
```

This of course does not compile since vars is not a compile-time constant in its length as known to compilers. The thing is, I can indeed know it's length at compile time, though the values are not known. And the problem is that if I expand the initializer list as variadic template, that would result in two variadic packs.

Do I *have to* pass explicit number parameter to the function? How do I achieve or approximate desired semantics?

EDIT: I don't have to return array, I just need to return a sequence of doubles, preferably on stack.

Comment: I personally view this as a defect of `constexpr` functions. You can try forwarding with tuples, makes the syntax uglier though

Comment: `std::array` is pretty much the closest you can get from returning a sequence of object on the stack. This and `std::tuple`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the size at compile-time, why not use a fixed-size array with the length as template parameter?

```
#include <array>

template < size_t N, class... Fs >
auto F(const double (&vars)[N], const Fs&... exprs) {
  return std::array<double, N>{};
}

int main()
{
  auto a = F({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
}
```